# How do we invoke methods that call StateHasChanged in Blazor Bunit unit tests

Tags: async-await, blazor, bunit

Consider the following Blazor component:

```cs
@page "/"
<p id="message">@message</p>

@code {

    string message = "Hello!";

    public Task UpdateMessage(string newMessage)
    {
        message = newMessage;
        StateHasChanged();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And the Bunit test that unit tests the above code:

```cs
using Bunit;

namespace BlazorTest.Client.Tests
{
    public class IndexTests : TestContext
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task MessageIsUpdated()
        {
            var component = RenderComponent<Pages.Index>();
            Assert.Equal("Hello!", component.Find("#message").TextContent);
            await component.Instance.UpdateMessage("Hello world!");
            Assert.Equal("Hello world!", component.Find("#message").TextContent);
        }
    }
}
```

This throws an exception saying:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException
 The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.
```

Please could I have some help explaining what this error means, and how to fix it so that I can unit test the functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task MessageIsUpdated()
{
    var component = RenderComponent<Pages.Index>();
    Assert.Equal("Hello!", component.Find("#message").TextContent);
    await component.InvokeAsync(() => component.Instance.UpdateMessage("Hello world!"));
    Assert.Equal("Hello world!", component.Find("#message").TextContent);
}
```

Comment: I like that better than my own approach. There could be other cases where it is essential to run tested code on the right context.

Comment: Thank you for contribution @Ethan. Great that it helps. If I might add: others would benefit a lot though from a brief explanation. :-) Would you mind adding one?

Comment: ok,help yourself @Jan

Answer (score 1):

First, you sample method does not really need StateHasChanged(), but for this question it is OK.

I don't know how execute tests with the proper Sync context, but you can adapt your code:

```
public Task UpdateMessage(string newMessage)
{
    message = newMessage;
    return InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    //return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

or, the more general pattern with async & await:

```
public async Task UpdateMessage(string newMessage)
{
    message = newMessage;
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```